# click event blocked by rotated element

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to learn a bit about css animations, and decided to try making a book with page turns (fixed animations not draggable)

I got the animations working well enough and now I'd like to stack pages on top of each other to form a book.  From what I can tell when the page flips, the outer div still occupies the original space, blocking my click event on the underlying page.

How can I get around this?

Here's a plunk demonstrating my issue http://plnkr.co/edit/2fPMgUvEKhdJLxJOOeBg

and the relevant CSS

```
.flipPage {
  animation: flip-page 1s 0s 1 linear alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.flipPageBack {
  animation: flip-page-back 1s 0s 1 linear alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.flipper {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;

  transform-origin: right;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;

}
.flipper > .front, .back {
  position:absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipper > .front {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color:coral;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.flipper > .back {
  background-color:lightcoral;
  transform: rotatey(180deg);
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

Comment: Either add anything that relates to Angular or remove the tag. I don't think that the question relates to Angular at all

Comment: @NewDev I included them because that's what my example uses, but you're right, angular is not relevant to the question itself.  I removed the tags